# Web Cam access using JavaFX

Tags: java, opencv, javafx, webcam

I've been searching for a solution to accessing a built-in webcam from a java or javaFX application. I've seen loads of other posts pointing to OpenCV and JavaCV, Sarxos's library and quite a few others.
I've run into difficulties such as newer versions of OpenCV not working with older code posted on various sites and newer code that uses OpenCV 3.0 is hard to find or doesn't do what I need, which is simply a customer application which saves an image taken from the web cam to a variable (or file).
Hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck. I toyed around with OpenCV last weekend and ran into the same problems as you. Here's an example about how to do it. The example opens the camera, uses an AnimationTimer (a bit overkill, but was a quick solution for prototyping) to grab a mat image periodically, converts the mat image to a JavaFX image, performs face detection and paints it on a canvas.

Here's what you need:

Download [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), e. g. in my case the windows version. Rename the opencv-3.0.0.exe to opencv-3.0.0.exe.zip and open it. Extract the contents of build/java.

Create a new JavaFX project. Put the jar and dlls into a lib folder, e. g.:

```
lib/opencv-300.jar
lib/x64/opencv_java300.dll
```

Add the jar to your build path.

In your src folder create a path opencv/data/lbpcascades and put the file lbpcascade_frontalface.xml in there (found in etc/lbpcascades). That's only for face detection, you can uncomment the code in case you don't need it.

Create the application class, code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class Camera extends Application {

    private static final int SCENE_W = 640;
    private static final int SCENE_H = 480;

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector;
    VideoCapture videoCapture;

    Canvas canvas;
    GraphicsContext g2d;
    Stage stage;
    AnimationTimer timer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        this.stage = stage;

        initOpenCv();

        canvas = new Canvas(SCENE_W, SCENE_H);
        g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        g2d.setStroke(Color.GREEN);

        Group group = new Group(canvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, SCENE_W, SCENE_H);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

        timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            Mat mat = new Mat();

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                videoCapture.read(mat);

                List<Rectangle2D> rectList = detectFaces(mat);

                Image image = mat2Image(mat);

                g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                for (Rectangle2D rect : rectList) {
                    g2d.strokeRect(rect.getMinX(), rect.getMinY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
                }

            }
        };
        timer.start();

    }

    public List<Rectangle2D> detectFaces(Mat mat) {

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale( mat, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        List<Rectangle2D> rectList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {

            int x = rect.x;
            int y = rect.y;
            int w = rect.width;
            int h = rect.height;

            rectList.add(new Rectangle2D(x, y, w, h));
        }

        return rectList;
    }

    private void initOpenCv() {

        setLibraryPath();

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
        videoCapture.open(0);

        System.out.println("Camera open: " + videoCapture.isOpened());

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            public void handle(WindowEvent we) {

                timer.stop();
                videoCapture.release();

                System.out.println("Camera released");

            }
        });

        faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(getOpenCvResource(getClass(), "/opencv/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"));

    }

    public static Image mat2Image(Mat mat) {
        MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mat, buffer);
        return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
    }

    private static void setLibraryPath() {

        try {

            System.setProperty("java.library.path", "lib/x64");

            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }

    public static String getOpenCvResource(Class<?> clazz, String path) {
        try {
            return Paths.get( clazz.getResource(path).toURI()).toString();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Of course you can do whatever you wish (e. g. saving) with the JavaFX image once you have it.

Comment: Thank you so much Roland, this is a great response. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

for sarxos, pseudo code, i can't publish whole class:

```
import com.sleepingdumpling.jvideoinput.Device;
import com.sleepingdumpling.jvideoinput.VideoFrame;
import com.sleepingdumpling.jvideoinput.VideoInput;

Device choosenDevice;
for (Device device : VideoInput.getVideoDevices()) {
// select your choosenDevice webcam  here
if (isMyWebcam(device)) {
choosenDevice = device;
break;

}
}
// eg. VideoInput(640,480,25,choosenDevice );
VideoInput videoInput = new VideoInput(frameWidth, frameHeigth,
                                frameRate, choosenDevice );
VideoFrame vf = null;
while (grabFrames) {
            vf = videoInput.getNextFrame(vf);
            if (vf != null) {
                frameReceived(vf.getRawData());
                // or vf.getBufferedImage();
            }

}
videoInput.stopSession();
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, I'll try this method out. Appreciate the reply.